# Measure the Max Memory of a running process in gcc-bookworm Docker image?

Tags: debian, time, gcc

I found many resources to use `valgrind` or `/usr/bin/time`. However, I need to perform this task in the container of the official Docker image for GCC: https://hub.docker.com/_/gcc

This image is based on Debian and Debian, unfortunately, does not have `/usr/bin/time`. It also doesn't have `valgrind` installed.

What can I use from the preinstalled packages in Debian that can do this job for me?

What would you recommend if none of the existing binaries can help me?